# Why is there a difference between my JSON output and RSS output in Yahoo Pipes

Tags: json, image, rss, pipe, yahoo

I have created a very simple pipe to find the first image of any item on a given rss feed, then use its url as a new item property (item.imageurl).

The pipe's output is now working in JSON but not in RSS. in RSS I don't see any  tag or the sort in any one of my items. It's basically a very simple pipe with a fetch feed then loop containing a fetch page module from the item.guid page (whic extracts the intended image url) and the assigning of first results to item.imageurl .

The important thing for me is to be able to use the rss format. That's it. Please help!

links:

[JSON output](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=2404bd6fac632284186f1c6f9e198ed2&_render=json)

[RSS Output](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=2404bd6fac632284186f1c6f9e198ed2&_render=rss)

Answer (score 0):

From [Yahoo pipes: how can I add an additional nodes/elements to RSS/feed items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048643/yahoo-pipes-how-can-i-add-an-additional-nodes-elements-to-rss-feed-items)

> That's because the RSS output of Yahoo Pipes removes all other fields that are not in the RSS standard. You can still see it in the JSON output though.